# I am not able to see my latest changes when new build is moved to production until unless refresh the browser

Tags: reactjs, caching, browser, refresh

I am using reactjs 16.4 version. When I move new  build to production environment i am not able to see my changes in production until refresh the browser.
I am using Amazon EC2 to move the build. We have two environments those are dev and prod environment with different hosts means it contains separate ip addresses .Amazon EC2 contains WinScp and ubuntu to move the app to virtual machine which exist in the cloud (Amazon EC2). for more details i am providing link here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Bhavani! Do you mean that you don't see the updated app in your browser until you refresh? That's the nature of browsers. All the files will be downloaded again first when you refresh.

Comment: Thanks Tholle!! but is there any solution to over come this problem means continuously hitting the server for updates or grab the changes when server get updated?? like that is there any possibilities.

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: I need to get latest changes in the production environment without refresh the browser when new build moved.

Comment: A few more questions for you - what are you hosting the app on (serverless vs server), what steps do you take to move the build from your dev environment into prod? The more information you can give, the more likely we'll be able to solve the problem :)

Comment: Sure @StephenGodderidge. Thanks for your suggestions. Edited the details under the  question section and i have given the link for more information. Please let me know if any additional details required.

Comment: Looks great! Ok, I agree with @Tholle - you won't be able to see the updated files until you refresh the browser. The newly-updated files will be passed over from EC2 to your browser, and then you can see the changes.

Comment: Thanks all by your suggestions i came to that it's not possible directly get changes without refresh the browser.